# Examples of non $\mathcal{F}^\infty$-measurable events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

For better clarity, I will report the definitions we are using: given a probability space  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a family $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ of independent random variables  $\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we define the $\sigma$-algebras:
$$\mathcal{F}^n := \sigma (X_n, X_{n+1}, \dots ) \qquad \qquad \mathcal{F}^\infty = \bigcap _{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}^n
$$

Clearly an event (or a random variable) is $\mathcal{F}^\infty$-measurable if and only if is $\mathcal{F}^n$-measurable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

> We want to see that the event
> $$\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \le 1 \right\}
> $$
> is not $\mathcal{F}^\infty$-measurable, while the event
> $$\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n < +\infty \right\}
> $$
> is $\mathcal{F}^\infty$-measurable.

Heuristically, it is clear to me that an event is $\mathcal{F}^\infty$-measurable if we can "remove" the first terms without changing nothing, so for example if the series $\sum _{n \ge1} X_n$ converges, then also the series $\sum _{n \ge n_0} X_n$ converges, for every $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Viceversa, we can have that $\sum _{n \ge 1}X_n >1$ and $\sum _{n \ge n_0}X_n \le 1$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

The point is that these are just heuristical observations, but I want to demonstrate these two facts in a mathematically rigorous manner. For example, I was trying to prove that the second event is $\mathcal{F}^n$-measurable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that the first event is not (which means that exists at least a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the first event is not $\mathcal{F}^{n_0}$-measurable), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You cannot prove that the first  set is never $\mathcal F^{\infty}-$ measurabe. It is, if $X_n=0$ for all $n$. You can only say that it is not $\mathcal F^{\infty}-$ measurabe **in general**.

Comment: Second one: $\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n < +\infty \right\}
=\left\{ \sum_{n=m}^\infty X_n < +\infty \right\}
$ for any $m$

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok, so for the first one I have to find a counterexample such that the event is not $\mathcal{F}^n$- measurable for some $n$, but for the second one, the only thing that is not very clear to me is why $\{ \sum _{n=m}^\infty X_n < +\infty \}$ is $\mathcal{F}^m$-measurable

Comment: Also, can you help me with the counterexample for the first one? I can't figure out how to construct it

Comment: Using my comment to answer the second one is very very elementary .  Have you studied basic properties of  measurable functions?  This is probably a homework question and you cannot ask for a complete solution.

Comment: @geetha290krm My only guess was that $\{\sum _{n=m}^\infty X_n < +\infty\}=(\sum_{n=m}^\infty )^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ so is $\mathcal{F}^m$-measurable because is the preimage of a Borel set via a $\mathcal{F}^m$-measurable function (is the limit of $\mathcal{F}^m$-measurable functions). I just wanted a confirm or an alternative way to say it. And also, is not a homework question but part of a lecture that I was trying to justify to make things clearer to me.

Comment: i.i.d $N(0,1)$ gives a example for the first one, but the proof requires some additional background about the space $\mathbb R^{\infty}$. In this case the set is not even in $\mathcal F^{2}$.